# React Context API, Data loading twice. Once with the data and the other without

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-context

Here is how I have created a Context for simple program I am writing

```
import React, { useState, createContext, useEffect } from "react";

export const PhotoContext = createContext();

export const PhotoProvider = (props) => {
  const [photo, setPhoto] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Use Effect Runs  HAHAHAH");
    console.log("HAHAHAHAHAHAHAH");
    fetchPhotos();

    async function fetchPhotos() {
      const url =
        "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bobziroll/scrimba-react-bootcamp-images/master/images.json";

  

      fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((arr) => {
          setPhoto(arr);
        })
        .catch(console.log("ERROR"));
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <PhotoContext.Provider value={[photo, setPhoto]}>
      {props.children}
    </PhotoContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

There is another file where I want to load the data in the photos variable. Here is the code for it. I have used setTimeout to see where exactly is the problem. It seems whenever the statement in setTimeout runs, the value in console in returned twice. First, it is empty and the second has the actual value. But since, I try to access the photos.url, and since the first time it is undefined, the program collapses.

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from "react";
import { PhotoContext } from "../Context/PhotoContext";

const Photos = (props) => {
  const [photos, values] = useContext(PhotoContext);

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(photos[0].url);
  }, 3000);
  return <div>{}</div>;
};

export default Photos;
```

Help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't see the problem. I created sandbox for your example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-lovelace-5r1gb?file=/src/App.js